# From a C++ Library code to a C application code: symbol lookup error

Tags: c++, c, compilation, linker, runtime-error

I have a C++ library and some C application code. In the C++ library, there is a function call to the C application function:

source code in the C++ library:

```
extern "C" {
  void foo();
}

...
void bar() { foo();}
```

And in my C code:

```
void foo() { 
 ...
}
```

Also symbol table of these two executables:

```
readelf -sW C_application | grep foo

71: 0000000000400b10  1159 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 foo

readelf -sW libcpp_library.so | grep foo

11: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  foo
```

However, when I execute the C appliation like:

```
LD_PRELOAD="/home/asd/libcpp_library.so" ./C_application
```

I got the following error:

```
./C_application: symbol lookup error: /home/asd/libcpp_library.so : undefined symbol: foo
```

I have no idea what is wrong here, so could anyone shed some light on potential cause of this issue?

Comment: Is there a definition of `foo` somewhere? You gave one for `bar`, which is irrelevant.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, of course, there are definitions of `foo` in the `C` application code.

Comment: show your link command

Comment: wait - the library calls the app ? "In the C++ library, there is a function call to the  C application function:"

Comment: Are you attempting to call a function in the executable from the library? That's not going to work.

Comment: @NeilButterworth , Yes, that's what I am going to do. Why it does not work? Is it because I didn't "export" function `foo` in the executable? And hence `foo` is not in the dynamic linkage table or so where?

Comment: @pm100 . Yes, the library has a missing symbol (function `foo`) and it is defined in the application code.

Comment: If you want to do something like that, add some initialization function to the library, taking a function pointer from the caller. And then use it to pass the `foo` from the executable.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That sounds feasible to me.. Thanks a lot! I will try it out soon.

Answer (score -1):

You need export your function to be available/visible from .so.
Detailed explanation can be found here: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility